# Using Rhomobile MapView not loading tiles only gray grid

Tags: android, android-mapview, rhomobile

I am trying to display a map using Rhomobile framework Rhodes

I have followed the [webinar](http://vimeo.com/12301104) and [tutorial](http://docs.rhomobile.com/mapping-tutorial)
I have done exactly the same, but my map tiles are not loading on my android device nor on the emulator.

I have generated the api key following the [instructions here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)
and I got the debug key: 05dXWxC1NSKgk7itJZnjJr1-AobLz3l5iN2iAWg

I added the key to my build.yml like this:

```
android:
  version: 2.1
  mapping: true
  apikey: 05dXWxC1NSKgk7itJZnjJr1-AobLz3l5iN2iAWg
```

in my controller I have the following:

```
   map_params = {
          :settings => {:map_type => "hybrid",:region => [@customer.lat, @customer.long, 0.2, 0.2],
                        :zoom_enabled => true,:scroll_enabled => true,:shows_user_location => false,
                        :api_key => 'Google Maps API Key'},
```

I have tried adding the apikey where it says Google Maps API Key but it still doesn't work. I [have read](http://groups.google.com/group/rhomobile/browse_thread/thread/2fffd180a08a0671/9f1c828fccf4862a?lnk=gst&q=map%20#9f1c828fccf4862a) that for Android there are two keys involved, but I only have one. Where do I get the other key if this is necessary?

I have also read in some threads that by setting the uses_permission to INTERNET in the android manifest it has solved the problem, but I don't know how to do that using rhodes framework. I have added the gps capabilities to the build.yml, but I can't seem to find that a internet capability exists in this framework.

I hope you can help me out. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in fact it wasn't a problem of my apikey.

The problem was solved by deleting the bin folder and recompiling the app... I guess all it needed was some sort of a clean build.

problem solved!

Comment: i am facing the same problem in my iphone simulator...i deleted the bin folder too..but i still see the blue color on my gmap..it doesnt show me the map...:(